# Verilog Parameter overriding

Tags: verilog

During parameter overriding,  the parameter my_secret is getting overridden by 2.3.4.5. I want to impose a condition that overrides my_secret to 2 for count = 0 to 10,  my_secret to 3 for count = 10 to 20,  my_secret to 4 for count = 20 to 30,   my_secret to 5 for count = 40 to 50 ?

Test bench:

```
module tb_def_param;

    // Inputs
    reg CLK;
    reg RST;
    reg [4:0] a;
    reg [4:0] b;
   reg  [5:0] count;
    parameter my_secret = 4'd0;
wire [6:0] sum;

    initial 
    begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        CLK = 1;
        RST = 1; 

        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #100 RST = 1;
      #100 RST = 0; 

        // Add stimulus here
        a = 5'd2;
        b = 5'd3;
    end

always @ (posedge CLK)
   begin
    if(RST)
        count <= 6'd0;
        else 
        count <= count + 1;
    end 

secret_number #(2) U0(.CLK(CLK), .RST(RST), .a(a),.b(b),.sum(sum));
secret_number #(3) U1(.CLK(CLK), .RST(RST), .a(a),.b(b),.sum(sum));
secret_number #(4) U2(.CLK(CLK), .RST(RST), .a(a),.b(b),.sum(sum));
secret_number #(5) U3(.CLK(CLK), .RST(RST), .a(a),.b(b),.sum(sum));

always
    begin
         #10 CLK <= ~CLK;
    end 

endmodule
```

main module is:

```
 module secret_number(CLK,RST,a,b,sum); 
 input CLK, RST;
 input [4:0]a,b;
 output [6:0]sum;
 reg [6:0] sum;
 parameter my_secret = 0;
 always@(posedge CLK)    
   sum = a + b + my_secret;
     initial begin
     $display("%d", my_secret);
            end
     endmodule
```

Is that possible ???

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use `count` to determine which value of `my_secret` is used in computing `sum`. You have most of what you need in your testbench module now, you are just missing is some logic to select between the resulting values from your various `secret_number` modules. You currently have all of those modules driving the same vector `sum` but they should really be driving separate vectors and then using combinational logic to select the desired result:

```
wire [6:0] sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5;
reg [6:0] sum;
secret_number #(2) U0(.CLK(CLK), .RST(RST), .a(a),.b(b),.sum(sum2));
secret_number #(3) U1(.CLK(CLK), .RST(RST), .a(a),.b(b),.sum(sum3));
secret_number #(4) U2(.CLK(CLK), .RST(RST), .a(a),.b(b),.sum(sum4));
secret_number #(5) U3(.CLK(CLK), .RST(RST), .a(a),.b(b),.sum(sum5));

always @(*) begin
  if (count <= 10) begin // Not sure if you want inclusive of 10, if not, do <
    sum = sum2;
  end
  else if (count <= 20) begin
    sum = sum3;
  end
  else if (count <= 30) begin
    sum = sum4;
  end
  else
    sum = sum5;
  end
end
```

However, you can also have `my_secret` be a input to the module rather than a parameter unless you need to use the `my_secret = 2` block when count is greater than 10 for something else. It will save a good amount of area if you do it as an input instead.

(Now also, inside the module it should be `sum <= a + b + my_secret`, use NBA (`<=`) for clocked blocks)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Sum is of "wire" type, it cannot be declared under always block. Any suggestions to over come this issue ?

Comment: Youre right; sorry; change `sum` to be a `reg` and it will work (Ill edit the above)

Comment: That's the issue there ... sum should be an output, i.e it should be a wire type.

Comment: And why is that a problem? Outputs can be declared type `reg`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was greatly helpful.